# How to split SQL Server Transaction Log

Tags: sql-server, database-design, transaction-log

My database server has just ran out of disk space. The Transaction log is taking over 100GB space and I have only 30GB free space. Because of this some transactions are taking infinite amount of time to process resulting in 9002 error.

I would like to ask is there a way I can split this transaction log and delete one of them to get some free space. There is no way now that I can take a backup or increase the disk space by adding another disk.

If any one has a better solution than splitting up the transaction log, then that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of good resources about dealing with large logs linked to from here:

https://sqlblog.org/2009/07/27/oh-the-horror-please-stop-telling-people-they-should-shrink-their-log-files

Basically, you either need to get more space, backup the logs, or switch to simple recovery mode on your databases.  Each approach has its ups and downs.

Answer (score 1):

in Practice

Data, Logs & OS should be on different disks...
say C for OS, E for Data, and L for Logs.

and if your transaction logs doesnt shrink after a transaction backup then you might want to check you setting.    FULL or Simple (doesnt shrink logs).

to force shrink a Log wherein database is set to simple is :

```
Alter database <databasename>set Recovery simple   /* if database is set to FULL */
USE <databasename>
DBCC SHRINKFILE (<log_name>, 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
Alter database <databasename> set Recovery full  /* if database is set to FULL */
```

hope this helps